# How to make an executable text file

Tags: file, ubuntu, executable

I am using Ubuntu, and I would like to make an executable text file. I have seen some source code of an executable text file, but I can't seem to understand anything. Could someone please show some code that shows the structure of an executable text file. Just to be more specific, I am trying to launch a .class file for an application. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about a bash script?

Comment: You probably want to use `java` ...

Comment: Instead of using the Terminal, I would just like to double click on the file, and launch my application

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for [UnityLaunchers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles).